# How do I abstract out a function as parameter in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am using async.js to do the following:

```
var async = require('async');
var i = 0;
var continueWhilst = true;
async.whilst(
  function test() { return continueWhilst; },
  function doThisEveryTime(next) {
    i++;
    if (i===5) {
      continueWhilst = false;
    }
    console.log(i);
    next();
  },
  function (err) {
    // Done
  }
);
```

The above worked. [This is the documentation for async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst).

Now I wanted to abstract out the `doThisEveryTime` function so the code's much readable. I tried doing this:

```
var i = 0;
var continueWhilst = true;
async.whilst(
  function test() { return continueWhilst; },
  doThisEveryTime2(next),
  function (err) {
    // Done
  }
);

function doThisEveryTime2(next) {
  i++;
  if (i===5) {
    continueWhilst = false;
  }
  console.log(i);
  next();
}
```

But it didn't work. The error message is as follow:

```
  doThisEveryTime2(next),
               ^
ReferenceError: next is not defined
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only pass the `doThisEveryTime` function, not call it - no parenthesis, no `next`:

```
var i = 0;
var continueWhilst = true;
async.whilst(
  function test() { return continueWhilst; },
  doThisEveryTime2,
  function (err) {
    // Done
  }
);
```

Also notice that you rather should use the [`timesSeries` function](https://github.com/caolan/async/#timesseriesn-callback) for what you are doing - with the additional benefit that `i` is a functional argument to the `doThisEveryTime` function, not a global variable.